# Regex - extract string between double quotes where line starts with a keyword

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following lines:

```
classes!("text-xl", "text-blue-500")
String::from("test")
classes!("text-sm")
```

I wish to extract `text-xl`, `text-blue-500` and `text-sm` and potentially any other strings within `classes!`

What I have so far is:

- `(?<=classes!).*` - this gives me everything after classes! but not
  the exact values
- `(?!^")".*?"` - this gives me the values I want with but with the quotes
- I use the global and multi line flags

Comment: Do you only wish to extract classes that begin "text-"?

Comment: @Dexygen no anything with in the double quotes so long as the line contains `classes!()`

Comment: Heh I started on a solution that only looked for "text=" but now I see the other good answers.

Comment: Apologies, probably should have made that clear! but either way thanks for the attempt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Javascript, and the positive lookbehind is supported (you don't need the multiline flag, only the global flag)

```
(?<=classes!\((?:"[^"]*",\s*)*")[^"]*(?=")
```

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind to assert to the left

  - `classes!\(` Match `classes!(`
  - `(?:"[^"]*",\s*)*` Match optional repetitions of `"...",`
  - `"` Match a double quote
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `[^"]*` Match optional chars other than `"`
- `(?=")` Assert `"` to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d6U06L/1)

```js
const regex = /(?<=classes!\((?:"[^"]*",\s*)*")[^"]*(?=")/g;
const str = `classes!("text-xl", "text-blue-500")
String::from("test")
classes!("text-sm")
`;
console.log(str.match(regex))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try a non fixed-width lookbehind like so:

```
(?<=^classes!\("(?:[^"]*"[^"()]*")*)[^"]*
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/R7AVrL/1)

---

- `(?<=` - Open a positive lookbehind;

  - `^classes!\("` - Start-line anchor and match literally 'classes!("';
  - `(?:[^"]*"[^()"]*")*` - A nested non-capture group to match (0+ times) any char other than quotes (and paranthesis), a quote and that same sequence repeated.
  - `)` - Close lookbehind;
- `[^"]*` - Match 0+ (Greedy) characters other than quotes.

Comment: Thanks, this also works - its unfortunate that I cannot mark multiple answers for a question!

Comment: @itsezc, that's completely fine. Nice to see the issue is fixed that quick.

Comment: ( I think if `classes!` should be there on the same line and not match `String::from("test")`you can exclude the parenthesis https://regex101.com/r/R7AVrL/1 )

Comment: @Thefourthbird, I see now what you meant since my pattern would still pick the unwanted string up. Ammended in the answer. Thanks!